# How to convert string with property name to Entity framework storage expression?

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I need to select specific columns from DB using string with property name in Entity Framework. I use reflections to be able pass complex properties:

```
public static Object GetPropValue(this Object obj, String name)
{
    foreach (String part in name.Split('.'))
    {
        if (obj == null) { return null; }

        Type type = obj.GetType();
        PropertyInfo info = type.GetProperty(part);
        if (info == null) { return null; }

        obj = info.GetValue(obj, null);
    }
    return obj;
}
```

Then I tried to pass this into Select like this:

```
string propertyName = "ModemStatus.Temperature"  // This is sent in http request
DBContext.MyStatuses.Select(x => x.GetPropValue(propertyName))
```

But I get runtime exception that GetPropValue can not be converted to storage expression, which I understand but I have no idea how to solve it. Any idea?

EDIT: Return type will always be a collection of doubles

```
 ICollection<double> values = DBContext.MyStatuses.Select(x => x.GetPropValue(propertyName))
```

Comment: Your problem is deeper: how would you dynamically build a runtime return type? Even anonymous types are known at compile time. Maybe Entity SQL with DbDataRecord is a more promising approach.

Comment: I forgot to mention that return type will be collection of doubles. Edited the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have found the solution using extenstions in System.Linq.Dynamic available at Nuget

http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2008/01/07/dynamic-linq-part-1-using-the-linq-dynamic-query-library.aspx

Then I can use string predicate in Select operations like this:

```
DBContext.MyStatuses.Select("ModemStatus.Temperature");
```